# French speech recognition on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, openears

I'm trying to develop an iOS app using speech-recognition for french language, but have been unsuccessful until now.
I tried using the openEars framework, which worked great for english language, but doesn't support french.
I used some info from this [link](http://www.politepix.com/forums/topic/other-languages/).

If anyone know a solution it would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: solution to what exactly..? getting the framework to support french?

Comment: Speech recognition actually must be supported on iOS through openEars. The text-to-speech does not. The models and everything else is availble on CMUSphinx website, you can just use them.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I tried to use the CMUSphinkx langage model direclty [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/French%20Language%20Model/)
but I think it is too big (62K words) so it doesn't recognize anything

Comment: Right, you can prune language model and reduce it's vocabulary to make it smaller. English model is small too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openers is using **English Acoustic and Language Models** by default. So it works well with english, but doesn't support french.

You can download French Acoustic and Language Models from [CMU Sphinx website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/)

Some good French Acoustic and Language Models are available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/French%20Language%20Model/french3g62K.lm.dmp.bz2/download)

Download & Change your Openears Acoustic and Language Models with this one.

To do this, just replace Openears **hub4wsj_sc_8k** folder with the downloaded one and replace the `.dic` and `.languagemodel` files with the downloaded ones.

If you think , the downloaded French Acoustic and Language Models are too big, then create our own with few words using this [documents](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that you had to replace the **hub4wsj_sc_8k** folder with an other acoustic model.
It works a little better, finding some words, but it's still too slow. I would have to create my own dictionary.

Comment: okay.. creating your own will take too much time. For this better to use Linux system. between 3-4 French Acoustic and Language Models available in CMU Sphinx website. Download and try all of them. Also search Acoustic and Language Models in google. You may get from other websites. Dont forget to replace your .language model file and .dic files along with the hub4wsj_sc_8k folder.or just make sure you are using French .language model and .dic files. finally Clean your project and run.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this library [iPhone-Speech-To-Text](https://github.com/todoroo/iPhone-Speech-To-Text) for my project.

It use the google voice api, sending a FLAC file of the speech and retrieving the appropriate text.

To make it work for french language, in `SpeechToTextModule.m` I juste changed the URL

> `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US"];`

to

> `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=fr"];`

Comment: Google voice services are great, but it is unfortunately not a public API.

Answer (score -1):

The alternative I found is Dragon Speech SDK for Mobile. You simply need to [Register With Dragon Mobile](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home) and download SDK and Samples.

It Supports English, French, German Speech Recognition. Also it is working very accurately than openEars. I have tested this for English and its working very well.

Here is screen for that sample which supports Recognition in mentioned language

[image]

**Note**

[The SDK is free to download and use for 90 days, but...](http://readwrite.com/2011/01/24/dragon-speech-sdk-arrives-for-android-ios)

Comment: I made a request earlier to try their sdk, but in the end I think it's too expensive.

Comment: Yes I know thats why I have mentioned that in Note